# Remove all elements in the HTML Collection

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. When I try to delete all the images, only 3 are getting remove. It feels so weird. What's the reason for this?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function c() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]) //or images[i].remove()
    }
  }
</script>
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="c()" />
```

Comment: You have to decrement i by 1 when you delete

Comment: You are redefining the images collection every time you delete think about it

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName): _"Returns an HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The complete document is searched, including the root node. **The returned HTMLCollection is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call document.getElementsByTagName() again.**"_ Either use `document.querySelectorAll` or delete the images "backwards"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop in reverse order. If you loop forwards, as you remove an element, you are modifying the index of the ones that remain.  So, do this instead:

```
for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // Remove first element (at [0]) repeatedly
  images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
```

Comment: If you always delete the "first" element you don't need to go in "reverse order".

Answer (score 4):

Just use a while loop

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function c() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var counter = 0;
    while(images.length){
      images[counter].parentNode.removeChild(images[counter])
    }
  }
</script>
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="c()" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  function c() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = images.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
      images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]) //or images[i].remove()
    }
  }

  function c1() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]) //or images[i].remove();
      //you can also decrement i by one with each delete, more than one way to skin a cat as they say.
      i--;
    }
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
<img src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Delete Images" onclick="c1()" />
```

To go along with my comment you can also iterate backwards to avoid having to adjust i with each iteration.

```
  for (var i = images.length-1; i >-1;  i--) {
      images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]) //or images[i].remove()
    }
```

Comment: You solution is not working and all your comments doesn't make sense.

Comment: look at the edit history of my post...it was right the first time I posted it. What are you talking about??

Comment: I'll add what I'm talking about in my comment.